# how to make user profiles be domain.com/username instead of domain.com/profile.php?user=username?

Tags: php, mysql, http, url, profile

I created a website where each member has a profile. I store their data in mysql database and I have a folder called pictures where I store members profile pictures with username as filename.
each member's username is unique.
I have one page called profile.php where I get user info using the php variable $_GET['user'] . 
the question is how do I make the user profile link be domain.com/username instead of domain.com/profile.php?user=username just like facebook,twitter and other websites  ? 
can I do this without making a separate folder for each member?
please help me because it will make easier access to profiles :)
like when facebook used to have profiles url like facebook.com/profile?id=2659265892689356298 how did they change it to be facebook.com/usern.name ?

Comment: one of the most asked questions here, please search first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis of your answer is in URL rewriting.  You don't say which HTTP server you are using, but if it is Apache 2, you should look at the [`mod_rewrite` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) and come back with more specific questions regarding any problems (after searching for answers).

Comment: I am using a apache 2 and windows

Comment: Just a free advice, switch to Linux.